# Is there a way to switch to the old netbook interface?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-netbook

Is there a way to switch to the old netbook remix interface? The one that was like easy peasy

[image]

I don't like the way unity looks like now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Old netbook launcher is at the moment available only for Natty.
Unfortunately I don't know nothing about the version for Precise.
I also like this launcher.

https://launchpad.net/~doctormo/+archive/netbook-launcher

https://launchpad.net/~doctormo/+archive/netbook-launcher/+packages

Comment: This does not provide a sufficient answer to the question. Try to add more information, and / or examples.

Answer (score 2):

More info about Old Netbook Launcher for Natty and install guide:
http://doctormo.org/2011/05/20/netbook-launcher-now-available-for-natty/

Answer (score 2):

The netbook interface is currently not available for 12.04 and above because of huge changes in GTK, Gnome and Ubuntu.

I'm working on the problem though by using a python/vala mixture to recreate the netbook interface using the same graphics and mechanics. The more support I can get from people who want this kind of interface the better.